# Clear Completed tasks button to-do List

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures

I've been working on a simple to-do list using jQuery and am running into a few issues. I created an edit button that works fairly well, but I want it so that when I press enter the text box becomes unselected and the text is no longer editable until the edit button is clicked again.

I am also trying to add a Clear Completed button that will clear all "Checked" items, but can't seem to target the right items to remove.  Any tips would be appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#todo").focus();

  function addItem() {
      $("#todo-items").append("<li><input type='checkbox' class='done'/><span>" + $("#todo").val() + "</span><button class='delete'>Delete</button><button class='edit'>Edit</button></li>");
      $("#todo").val("");
    }
    //add item when enter is pressed
  $("#todo").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13)
      addItem();
  });
  //add item when "Add" is clicked
  $("#add").click(addItem);

  //make textbox content editable
  $(document).on("click", '.edit', function() {
    $(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable", true).focus();

    //$(this).closest("span").keydown(function(e) {
    //if (e.which == 13) return false;
    //});
  })

  //delete item from list
  $(document).on("click", '.delete', function() {
      $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
      return false;
    })
    //strike-through text when checkbox is checked
  $(document).on("click", '.done', function() {
      if ($(this).closest("li").find("span").css('textDecoration') === 'line-through') {
        $(this).closest("li").find("span").css('textDecoration', 'none');
      } else {
        $(this).closest("li").find("span").css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
      }
    })
    //clear all completed tasks
  $(document).on("click", 'clear', function() {
    if ($(this).closest("li").find("span").css('textDecoration') === 'line-through') {
      $(this).parent().remove();

    }
  })

});
```

```css
body {
  font: sans-serif;
  color: #00b33c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 700px;
}
li {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #e5ffff;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  width: 500px;
}
li span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="todolistjquery2.js"></script>

<body>

  <h1>To Do List</h1>

  <div>

    <input type="text" id="todo" />
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />

  </div>

  <div id="completed">

    <input type="button" value="Clear Completed" id="clear" />


  </div>

  <ul id="todo-items"></ul>

</body>
```

Comment: I have answered and it is working... `:)` Kindly check and respond back. Sorry for the delay. `:)`

Comment: Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your queries:

1. **I want it so that when I press enter the text box becomes un-selected and the text is no longer editable until the edit button is clicked again.**

   Use this code:

   ```
   // finalize the edited span
   $(document).on("keydown", 'span[contenteditable]', function (e) {
     if (e.which == 13) {
       $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable").blur();
       return false;
     }
   });
   ```
2. **Clear Completed button that will clear all "Checked" items, but can't seem to target the right items to remove.**

   You have an error in the code. You need to use `#clear` and not just `clear`.

   ```
   //clear all completed tasks
   $(document).on("click", '#clear', function() {
     $(".done:checked").each(function () {
       $(this).closest("li").remove();
     });
   })
   ```

See the **final working snippet**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#todo").focus();

  function addItem() {
    $("#todo-items").append("<li><input type='checkbox' class='done'/><span>" + $("#todo").val() + "</span><button class='delete'>Delete</button><button class='edit'>Edit</button></li>");
    $("#todo").val("");
  }
  //add item when enter is pressed
  $("#todo").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13)
      addItem();
  });
  //add item when "Add" is clicked
  $("#add").click(addItem);

  //make textbox content editable
  $(document).on("click", '.edit', function() {
    $(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable", true).focus();
    //$(this).closest("span").keydown(function(e) {
    //if (e.which == 13) return false;
    //});
  })
  //delete item from list
  $(document).on("click", '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
  })
  //strike-through text when checkbox is checked
  $(document).on("click", '.done', function() {
    if ($(this).closest("li").find("span").css('textDecoration') === 'line-through') {
      $(this).closest("li").find("span").css('textDecoration', 'none');
    } else {
      $(this).closest("li").find("span").css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
    }
  });
  //clear all completed tasks
  $(document).on("click", '#clear', function() {
    $(".done:checked").each(function () {
      $(this).closest("li").remove();
    });
  })
  // finalize the edited span
  $(document).on("keydown", 'span[contenteditable]', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable").blur();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: sans-serif;
  color: #00b33c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 700px;
}
li {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #e5ffff;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  width: 500px;
}
li span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="todolistjquery2.js"></script>
<h1>To Do List</h1>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="todo" />
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />
</div>

<div id="completed">
  <input type="button" value="Clear Completed" id="clear" />
</div>
<ul id="todo-items"></ul>
```